# put buttons in images made by view pager?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-viewpager

I've made an image slider with a ViewPager and Picasso. And, also I did next, prev in java but I'm facing trouble while placing those buttons in the bottom of ImageView.

Buttons are seen but they are not overlapping images, instead, they are separated.

XML code of activity where i've shown image slider using ViewPager

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next"
            android:id="@+id/btn_next"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Previous"
            android:id="@+id/btn_previous"/>

    </LinearLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.recyclerview_codelabs.MainActivity">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Change the root view group in the layout to be `FrameLayout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use this, it will work fine.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.recyclerview_codelabs.MainActivity">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next"
            android:id="@+id/btn_next"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Previous"
            android:id="@+id/btn_previous"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ViewPager should be on top of hierarchy, Otherwise those button overlapped by viewpager and won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it work fine for you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent">



   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.recyclerview_codelabs.MainActivity">
   </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        android:id="@+id/btn_next"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Previous"
        android:id="@+id/btn_previous"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This property only work in Relativelayout

```
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```